# Regex multiple matches on multiple lines

Tags: javascript, c#, regex

I have this data, effectively a markdown table:

```
blah blah blah
| Tables        | Are           | Cool  |
| ------------- |:-------------:| -----:|
| col 3 is      | right-aligned | $1600 |
| col 2 is      | centered      |   $12 |
| zebra stripes | are neat      |    $1 |
blah blah
blah
```

I would like to do a regex match and get the values between the pipes out.

Ideally, I'd like to get a group for each line, and then a subgroup with each 'cell'.

Even more ideally, I'd like to make sure there are the same number of cells/columns in each row.

My attempts either match the last cell in the row/table, or every second cell. This just bombs out totally:
`\|(?:([^\r\n\|]*)\|)+\r?\n\|(?:(\:?-+\:?)\|)+\r?\n(\|(?:([^\r\n\|]*)\|)+\r?\n)+`

This is also pretty dismal: `^#(?:([^#]+)#)+$`

Looking for a solution in javascript or C#.

Comment: Is input a single string ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd go in js with something like this, but only if you don't need the regex for something else ;-)

```
var yourStr
var groups = yourStr.split('\n')
var cells = yourStr.split('|')
if (cells.length < asItShouldBe) { ... }
var cell1 = cells[1]
var cell2 = cells[2]
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
var input = document.querySelectorAll("pre")[0].innerText;
var output = input.match(/\s+|\w+-\w+|\w+|\W+\d+|\d+/gi)
             .map(function(word, i) {
               return word.replace(/\||\s|--+|\s-\s+|:/gi, "")
             });

document.body.insertBefore(
  document.createTextNode(output.join(" "))
, document.getElementsByTagName("hr")[0]
);
```

```html
<hr />
<pre>
blah blah blah
| Tables        | Are           | Cool  |
| ------------- |:-------------:| -----:|
| col 3 is      | right-aligned | $1600 |
| col 2 is      | centered      |   $12 |
| zebra stripes | are neat      |    $1 |
blah blah
blah
</pre>
```